# Rails 3 application errors in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I have application on Rails 3. Everything works just fine, but as we know best performance should be on Production mode.

When I set environment as Production in Justhost control panel and in environment.rb file
with

```
 # Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
Darbs::Application.initialize!

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'
```

And `touch tmp/restart.txt`

It gives me error:
Ruby (Rack) application could not be started

```
Error message:
Admin is not a class
```

And when I check current environment with Rail.env.production? it returns `false`.
I tried several restarts and so on without success.

in production log file I get `Connecting to database specified by database.yml`
It means some problem with connecting with specified database?
Any suggestions ?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you got your symbolic links set up in your web server?

Comment: @RichPeck Yes, I have done that.

Comment: Hmm - I only asked because it looks like Rails is not accessing the files it needs to run; hence the error appearing

Comment: @RichPeck Before I set production mode everything worked just fine in development mode. Thanks